# Issue regarding Regular Expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to match all "the act" outside the tags in the *.sgm that my professor gave me, I know that we can use XML parser, but our goal is to learn REGEX purely.

this is my current Regex:

```
(?<![""=<\/])\bthe act\b(?!\>)
```

The problem is with this example:

```
<ptext>Test example the act example</ptext>
```

My regex matches "the act". And that is correct.

But if this example now I will try:

```
<ptext tags="Test the act">Example the act</ptext>
```

The regex will match (2) two "the act", the one that is inside the tag attribute and the one outside, I dont want to match all the act inside the tag, how can I do that? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will work: `(?<=\>[^>]*)the act(?=[^<]*\<)` It should work if the regex engine allows variable length look behind, I think c#'s engine does.

Comment: this works, but when I try <ptext>Test <emphasis tag="test the act">Test</emphasis></ptext>..... It still matches the act inside the emphasis tag.

Comment: if your input looks like that you should also match the opening bracket of the tag. I'll adjust in a minute.

Comment: Thanks david, sorry for being a newbie.

Comment: I think maybe there's a more concise option, but this one might work: (?<=\<[^<>]*\>[^><]*)the act(?=[^><]*\<[^><]*\>)

Comment: that's it! Yeah it works! You're superb in REGEX! thanks! You save my day!

Comment: David, can I ask you a question again? What if I also don't want to match all of the letters inside the parenthesis? How can I do that? I mean I don't want my regex to match (the act)? thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What exactly do you want to match? Can you give an example?